# Accessing specified data to display on a web page

Tags: database, dynamic, hyperlink, spreadsheet

I have spent several hours on the web trying to find something that will work with what I want to do. I want the data entry to be very easy. Do NOT want to use mySQL as it appears to be rather complicated and time consuming.

I have come to the conclusion that possibly using a spreadsheet may be the way to go. Here is what I want to do:

Create a database (spreadsheet?) that has three elements that I will enter data into so two of them will display on a dynamic website.

1. Search term (category) that will determine which info will display on a specific page. Only items that match the search term would display. The page will automatically query the database for the desired search term and then display the results for that search term.
2. The URL for a link to a web page (starting with http://).
3. The NAME for the link.

Additional columns that would work to complete the links (all the same).

4. <a href="
5. ">
6. 

When all put together in the correct order the entry would appear as a link.

In other words, once the page queries the database based on the search term the page would display all of the items that match the search term. The search term itself would not appear in the listing(s).

The page itself would show the search term as the title of the page.

I hope this has been easy to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share what you have done so far and your code so we can know what improvements or recommendations we can give. If you have not tried anything yet, we recommend that you try and provide your efforts in the question section.

Comment: I have only looked for a simple program that will do what I want to do. I am hoping someone can point me to such a program (or at least coding to do it). Thanks for your reply.

Comment: grab https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create create sample of dataset and example of desired result and share the spreadsheet with us